# vectorize a loop using numpy

Tags: python, image, numpy

I am working on image file. Need help in converting following loop in vectorize form

```
for i in range(height):
  for j in range(width):
    print(j,i)
    start1[i, j, 0] = -0.5 + j / (width - 1)
    start1[i, j, 1] = (-0.5 + i / (height - 1)) * height / width
    start1[i, j, 2] = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Down below I provide two solution, one is using just `numpy`, another one using `numpy`+`numba`, both can be installed using `python -m pip install numpy numba`.

[Try next code online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64606814#main.py)

```
import numpy as np

# -------- Version 1, vectorized ----------

height, width = 2, 4
start1 = np.zeros((height, width, 3), dtype = np.float64)
start1[:, :, 0] = -0.5 + np.arange(width)[None, :] / (width - 1)
start1[:, :, 1] = (-0.5 + np.arange(height)[:, None] / (height - 1)) * height / width
print(start1)

# -------- Version 2, vectorized ----------

import numba

@numba.njit(cache = True)
def compute_start1(height, width):
    start1 = np.zeros((height, width, 3), dtype = np.float64)
    for i in range(height):
        for j in range(width):
            start1[i, j, 0] = -0.5 + j / (width - 1)
            start1[i, j, 1] = (-0.5 + i / (height - 1)) * height / width
            start1[i, j, 2] = 0
    return start1

print(compute_start1(2, 4))
```

Output:

```
[[[-0.5        -0.25        0.        ]
  [-0.16666667 -0.25        0.        ]
  [ 0.16666667 -0.25        0.        ]
  [ 0.5        -0.25        0.        ]]

 [[-0.5         0.25        0.        ]
  [-0.16666667  0.25        0.        ]
  [ 0.16666667  0.25        0.        ]
  [ 0.5         0.25        0.        ]]]


[[[-0.5        -0.25        0.        ]
  [-0.16666667 -0.25        0.        ]
  [ 0.16666667 -0.25        0.        ]
  [ 0.5        -0.25        0.        ]]

 [[-0.5         0.25        0.        ]
  [-0.16666667  0.25        0.        ]
  [ 0.16666667  0.25        0.        ]
  [ 0.5         0.25        0.        ]]]
```

I provided Numba solution because it is a nice package, it allows you to make very fast code just of regular python code. No need even to think about how to implement your code as numpy functions. Almost any quite simple code can be boosted by numba, up to `50-200x` times.

[Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) is a [Just-In-Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) compiler that converts python code to C++ and then to fast machine code, this boosts original code by around `100x` times on average! It is as fast and even sometimes faster than using NumPy. Also it is very closely related to numpy, it supports all numpy functions inside and even can parallelize them by providing `parallel = True` argument to `njit` function decorator, see [this jit documentation](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/jit-compilation.html#jit-functions) for reference.

In most cases in order to vectorize and boost `100x` times your code you just need to add `@numba.njit` line before your function and you're done. Of cause Numba can compile to pure fast C++ not any code, but most of quite simple algorithms involving a lot of loops/conditions/etc and numerical and/or numpy operations can be compiled and boosted by Numba.

Next is time measuring code for all three solutions (one non-vectorized and two vectorized). Needs installing one time modules by `python -m pip install numpy numba timerit`.

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64606814var2#main.py)

```
import numpy as np

# -------- Version 0, non-vectorized ----------

def f0(height, width):
    start1 = np.zeros((height, width, 3), dtype = np.float32)
    for i in range(height):
        for j in range(width):
            start1[i, j, 0] = -0.5 + j / (width - 1)
            start1[i, j, 1] = (-0.5 + i / (height - 1)) * height / width
    return start1

# -------- Version 1, vectorized ----------

def f1(height, width):
    start1 = np.zeros((height, width, 3), dtype = np.float32)
    start1[:, :, 0] = -0.5 + np.arange(width)[None, :] / (width - 1)
    start1[:, :, 1] = (-0.5 + np.arange(height)[:, None] / (height - 1)) * height / width
    return start1

# -------- Version 2, vectorized ----------

import numba

@numba.njit(cache = True, fastmath = True)
def f2(height, width):
    start1 = np.zeros((height, width, 3), dtype = np.float32)
    for i in range(height):
        for j in range(width):
            start1[i, j, 0] = -0.5 + j / (width - 1)
            start1[i, j, 1] = (-0.5 + i / (height - 1)) * height / width
    return start1

# -------- Time measuring ----------

from timerit import Timerit
Timerit._default_asciimode = True

h, w = 256, 512
ra, rt = None, None
for f in [f0, f1, f2]:
    print(f'{f.__name__}: ', end = '', flush = True)
    tim = Timerit(num = 15, verbose = 1)
    for t in tim:
        a = f(h, w)
    if ra is None:
        ra, rt = a, tim.mean()
    else:
        t = tim.mean()
        assert np.allclose(a, ra)
        print(f'speedup {round(rt / t, 3)}x')
```

Output:

```
f0: Timed best=159.324 ms, mean=159.855 +- 0.4 ms
f1: Timed best=1.212 ms, mean=1.257 +- 0.0 ms
speedup 127.178x
f2: Timed best=1.294 ms, mean=1.310 +- 0.0 ms
speedup 122.065x
```

Comment: Thanks for solution. Can you provide some reference material about vectorization

Comment: @KetanChaudhari Just added time measurements for my solutions, they give almost same `125x` times speedup! I didn't use any reference material for my code, just taken all my knowledge from head. Don't even know what to suggest, I gained all knowledge by just Googling.

Comment: @KetanChaudhari Regarding Numba I can tell next thing, basically almost always you just add `@numba.njit` line before your function and done, you're boosted `100x` times! See last time measuring code in my answer, look at `f0` and `f2`, it is totally same function code just with `@numba.njit` line added before and `f2` runs `125x` times faster than `f0` just because of one line. You may read about jit/njit decorator [in this documentation](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/jit-compilation.html#jit-functions).

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage NumPy`s broadcasting to avoid looping here:

```
# example image
from sklearn.datasets import load_sample_image
china = load_sample_image('china.jpg')

china.shape
# (427, 640, 3)

height, width, _ = china.shape

vec = china.copy()
i = np.arange(height)
j = np.arange(width)
vec[..., 0] = -0.5 + j / (width - 1)
vec[..., 1] = (-0.5 + i[:,None] / (height - 1)) * height / width
vec[..., 2] = 0
```

Checking we get the same:

```
op = china.copy()
for i in range(height):
  for j in range(width):
    op[i, j, 0] = -0.5 + j / (width - 1)
    op[i, j, 1] = (-0.5 + i / (height - 1)) * height / width
    op[i, j, 2] = 0

np.array_equal(op, vec)
# True
```

Timing comparisson (up to a `558x` speedup!):

```
%%timeit
for i in range(height):
  for j in range(width):
    op[i, j, 0] = -0.5 + j / (width - 1)
    op[i, j, 1] = (-0.5 + i / (height - 1)) * height / width
    op[i, j, 2] = 0
# 365 ms ± 27.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
vec[..., 0] = -0.5 + j / (width - 1)
vec[..., 1] = (-0.5 + i[:,None] / (height - 1)) * height / width
vec[..., 2] = 0
# 654 µs ± 33.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```